# Postgres сумма за разные интервалы?

Tags: postgresql

Возможно ли реализовать следующее - одним запросом получать сумму и за текущий день и за текущий месяц?

```
select
  sum(value::real) as sum
FROM 
  analiz_data 
--and CURRENT_DATE =f_timestamp::date
--and to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(f_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
sum(value::REAL) as month_sum,
sum(case when CURRENT_DATE =f_timestamp::date then value::REAL else 0 end) as today_sum
from analiz_data 
where to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(f_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM')
```